# Assign weights based on frequency of occurrence of values

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency

I would like to ask you for help with my data frame. It is a vector of many phases and for every one we have names of variables. Lets say

```
vec<-data.frame(phase1= c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5","var6"),     
                 phase2= c("var1","var3","var4","var2","var6","var5"),    
                 phase3= c("var4","var3","var2","var1","var6","var5"))

 vec
  phase1 phase2 phase3
1   var1   var1   var4
2   var2   var3   var3
3   var3   var4   var2
4   var4   var2   var1
5   var5   var6   var6
6   var6   var5   var5
```

Now, lets say we are interested for the first 3 rows and therefore the weight of variable in one of them is 1/3, zero otherwise. My function would ideally output sth like that:

```
          phase1 phase2 phase3
   var1   0.33   0.33    0
   var2   0.33   0       0.33
   var3   0.33   0.33    0.33
   var4   0      0.33    0.33
   var5   0      0       0
   var6   0      0       0
```

The function should also be applicable for the first 4, 5 or all 6 rows (ie the weights will change then).
Regards,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for this:

```
n<-3
l<-dim(vec)[1]
wghts<-c(rep(1/n, n), rep(0, l-n))
result<-do.call(cbind, lapply(vec, function(curcol){
        wghts[match(curcol, vec$phase1)]
    }))
```

If need be, you could add:

```
rownames(result)<-vec$phase1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%` to find matches and `ifelse` to set weigths:

```
set_weigth <- function(x, v, w) ifelse(x%in%v,w,0)
as.data.frame(lapply(vec, set_weigth, v=vec$phase1[1:3], w=0.33))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially setting the weight of `var_i` in `phase_i` as the fraction of rows `var_i` occurs in `phase_i`. The simplest way is to use the `table()` function: given a vector of discrete values, it produces a frequency-count of the different values. If you want to get your desired weights based on the first 3 rows of the data-frame `vec`, you simply do:

```
> sapply(vec[1:3,],table)/3

        phase1    phase2    phase3
var1 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
var2 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333
var3 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
var4 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
var5 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
var6 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

Similarly if you want to use the first 4 rows you do:

```
> sapply(vec[1:4,],table)/4
     phase1 phase2 phase3
var1   0.25   0.25   0.25
var2   0.25   0.25   0.25
var3   0.25   0.25   0.25
var4   0.25   0.25   0.25
var5   0.00   0.00   0.00
var6   0.00   0.00   0.00
```